# PySpark Run Multiple Functions on an RDD

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

Hello So I have example code:

```
for column in position:
    myData = dataSplit.map(lambda arr: (arr[column]))\
        .map(lambda line: line.split(','))\
        .map(lambda fields: ("Column", fields[0]))\
        .map(lambda (column, value) : value)\
        .filter(lambda line : filterWithAccum(line))\
        .map(lambda (value) : float(value))\
        .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    results.append(myData.sum())
    results.append(myData.stats())
    results.append(myData.variance())
    results.append(myData.sampleStdev())
    results.append(myData.sampleVariance())
```

Is there a way to run in one passultiple functions instead of 5 passes running each 1 function? The persist saves a lot of time but I feel like there has to be a better way to condense these. I originally had .min() .max() .mean() but .stats() does those for you so that condensed a few down already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get your question, however the `StatCounter` object returned by the `.stats()` method already has `sum`,`variance`,`sampleStddev` and `sampleVariance` fields. So you can do

```
statCounter = myData.stats()
results.append(statCounter.sum())
results.append(statCounter.min())
results.append(statCounter.variance())
results.append(statCounter.sampleStdev())
results.append(statCounter.sampleVariance())
```

Comment: When I run .stats() all I get is: (count: 4488, mean: 1.0, stdev: 0.0, max: 1.0, min: 1.0)

Comment: Look at the ScalaDoc rather than the PythonDoc, I found it more detailed.